# JavaScript runtime error: 'Selected' is undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<a id=\"01\" onClick=\"Selected('01');\" href=\"<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>/Pages/Admin/ManageUser.aspx\" class=\"submenu slider-black VerMenu \" style=\"width:120px;border-bottom:0px;\"><img src=\"<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>/Images/green-arow.gif\" border=\"0\" style=\"padding-left:5px\" />&nbsp;Delete Item </a>
```

I'm trying to create a hyperlink using the above JavaScript code. It works in chrome but throws the following error in IE 11 but i can't seem to figure out what i'm missing. Below is the error message is IE 11

> JavaScript runtime error: 'Selected' is undefined

Comment: Well, if JS complains it's not defined - it's not defined.

Comment: Is `nClick` a custom property? And yup, @zerkms is right. Somehow `Selected` is `undefined`, maybe out of scope?

Comment: @nem typo, corrected.

Comment: Show your `function Selected(string)` implementation please.

Comment: why are you escaping the quotes?